# Violation of pauli's exclusion principle? ( During formation of neutron star or black holes)

Tags: quantum-chemistry

**Sorry it's a bit long**

so i was watching Action labs video on how neutron stars are formed and in that he says " if there's enough mass, then the mass will keep on collapsing in on itself in the star and will collapse more until actual electrons are so close that the only thing that is stopping them from overlapping each other is Pauli's exclusion principle ,but if there is too much mass then even the Pauli's exclusion principle cannot keep the electrons from getting closer together ,so electrons get closer to protons leading to electron capture " **so i wanted to ask if formation of neutron star, or formation of Black hole leads to violation of Pauli's exclusion principle?**
I tried searching this on quora and physics stack but i couldn't get a simple explanation, there were some contradictory answers. some people said in case of formation of Black holes, degenerate mass is formed and that Pauli's exclusion principle cannot be violated on earth but in space during formation of Black holes or neutron stars, while some said it can't be violated ever.

Comment: I would not underestimate physicists  for this topic. Chemists are renown of refusing to put a piece of black hole into a test tube.. (joking, but seriously)

Comment: To be clear, it's not that Pauli's exclusion principle suddenly "stops applying" to electrons, it's just that new states of matter with fewer electrons become more energetically favorable, exactly *because* PEP still applies to electrons - it gets to a point where the overall energy of a system is lowered by *destroying the electrons* so PEP doesn't force there to be super-high energy electrons. A similar thing happens to neutrons in a neutron star at the brink of collapsing into a black hole.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is completely off-topic.

Comment: The key point about Neutron stars is that *they don't have any electrons*, so Pauli is irrelevant. *Nuclear* processes lead to the consumption of electrons by protons to give neutrons, leaving no electrons.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine the Pauli exclusion principle (PEP) in white dwarf context like side shrinking of a layer of identical balls laying on the floor. When shrinked enough and no free place for all balls, the extra balls would start another, upper layer. And another layer. And another... And you would need progressively higher side pressure to continue.

When matter is being squeezed in white dwarfs, PEP forces electrons with overlapping wavefunctions to fill progressively higher and higher energy levels, not to be in the same quantum state. That leads to progressively higher needed pressure which stops dwarf contraction.

If matter is squeezed enough, electrons have high enough energy and are tightly localized near protons. That leads at some tipping point to the nuclear reaction capturing electrons:

$\ce{p + e -> n + \nu_e}$

and gravitation squeezing can continue.

For white dwarfs it is interrupted by runaway nucleus fusion and supernova 1A event.

Massive stars skip the white dwarf state, but the [matter degeneration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_matter), driven by PEP, happens for the iron non-fusable core.

Such stars end in a supernova II event due runaway fusion due shock wave bouncing fusing layers and form a neutron star. More massive ones form a black hole.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Pauli's princinple, for the electron at least, is about the fundamental mathematical formulation of wavefunctions in chemistry- which do not matter to black holes as they deal with the nuclei. Just like how chemical properties do not matter to radioactivity.